# $\inf_{x\in A}{\limsup_nd(x_n, x)} = \limsup_n[\inf_{x\in A}d(x_n, x)] $ for compact subset $A$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, limsup-and-liminf, supremum-and-infimum

let $ (X, d) $ be a complete metric space, $ A\subset X $ be  compact and take a sequence  $ (x_n) \subset X $\ $ A $ as a bounded sequence.

Since infimum is independent from n , does the following hold?

$$ \inf_{x\in A}{\limsup_nd(x_n, x)} = \limsup_n[\inf_{x\in A}d(x_n, x)]  $$

I failed to find counterexample.

If it is not true, please give a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A=\{-1,1\}$, $X=\Bbb R$ and $x_n=(-1)^n$. LHS is $2$, while RHS is $0$.

**After the additional request $x_n\notin A$:** Consider the same $A$ and $$x_n=\begin{cases}4&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\ -3&\text{if }n\text{ is odd} \end{cases}$$ $$d(x_n,1)=4,3,4,3,4,3,\ldots\\ d(x_n,-1)=2,5,2,5,2,5,\ldots$$
so LHS is $4$, while RHS is $3$.

Comment: what about if $ (x_n) $ is not in A?

Comment: @seniormath Pick $\tilde x_n=1000+x_n$: you'll get $1002$ and $1000$.

Comment: i think i cant get 1002 at RHS because for -1 and for 1, $ | 1000+(-1)^n -1|$ and $ | 1000+(-1)^n +1|$ are two sequence which have limit superior 1000 and 1002.  by infimum on elements of A then it is 1000 am i wrong?

Comment: sorry for write RHS it will be LHS

Comment: I think you are right, I'm editing accordingly.

Comment: @seniormath Now the counterexample should be ok. I invite you to double-check the numbers, though.

Comment: it is true that LHS is 2 while RHS is 3. yes there is no equality. And now it is look like RHS is greater than LHS. it can be hold?

Comment: LHS is $4$, because $\limsup_n d(x_n,1)=4$ and $\limsup_n d(x_n,-1)=5$. RHS is $3$ because $$\min(d(x_n,1), d(x_n,-1))=\begin{cases}\min(3,5)=3&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\\min(4,2)=2&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$ RHS is always *smaller* that LHS because, for a fixed $x\in A$, and any $n$, $$d(x_n,x)\ge \inf_{y\in A} d(x_n,y)$$ hence, for all $x\in A$, $$\limsup_n d(x_n,x)\ge \limsup_n\inf_{y\in A} d(x_n,y)$$ hence $$\inf_{x\in A}\limsup_n d(x_n,x)\ge\inf_{x\in A}\limsup_n\inf_{y\in A} d(x_n,y)$$ but $$\inf_{x\in A}\limsup_n\inf_{y\in A} d(x_n,y)=\limsup_n\inf_{y\in A} d(x_n,y)$$